# Is there a way to, in a time input, put a lower value in max attribute than the min?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to, in a input time, put, for example, the attributes min="06:00:00" and max="01:00:00". What I'm trying to do is like a schedule for a job. Imagine you start at 06:00:00 am and go home at 01:00:00 am.
Is there one way that I can do this?

---

And with this, I have another problem, imagine if the start is at 23:00:00 and the end is at 01:00:00, I can't validate the end time to be after the start time.

---

Don't know if this is possible, hope you can help me.

PS: I don't want dates, just time.

Comment: `Imagine you start at 06:00:00 am and go home at 01:00:00 am` that's a long day :p - don't use min/max, use code to "validate" the time instead

Comment: `imagine if the start is at 23:00:00 and the end is at 01:00:00` - if end < start then add 24 hours to end, then validate (if number of hours between start and end is a validation criteria)

Comment: Your question is a little broad to get a good answer. Have you tried anything yet and can you add what you have tried and doesn't work to your question?